# Why should I use W-100 on Row on Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my project, the container is fluid and it is taking full width. But the row after it is only taking about 60%.

Images

Container:

[image]

Row:

[image]

Why does this happen when using examples of Bootstrap Documentation the row is full width? Img for contextualization:

[image]

Comment: What you post a question, please add the code/markup to the question instead of images.

Comment: @Themes.guide What I wanted to show was how much of the page the div's (container and row) were taking, not fully the code since it's for beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

## Don't use the Bootstrap 4 grid `row`>`col` inside the Navbar.

The Navbar is designed to contain only the [supported content](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#supported-content) and not the grid. Use the [utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) to align or set width for the Navbar content as desired. Since the Navbar is display:flex child items will follow flexbox rules.

**Explanation:**

> "Why does this happen when using examples of Bootstrap Documentation
>   the row is full width?"

Because the documentation isn't using the row>col inside a flexbox Navbar.

When you use a `container-fluid` inside the Navbar it is `display:flex` which uses `align-items:flex-start` by default. This causes the `row` to stick to the left (flex-start) side, and it won't stretch across to full-width unless width:100% (w-100) is used on the the `row`.

Comment: So as you said, "Don't use the Bootstrap 4 grid row > col inside the Navbar"! Thank you! For now, no rows on navbar